# contact force sensing

Tags: gazebo-sensor, contact

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It seems that there is a bump/force sensor that works for contact on a link.  However, does this scale or is there another implemented sensor that would allow me to get contact forces all over a robot arm?  Essentially, I'd like to simulate tactile sensing.  I have implemented and used something similar in ODE directly, but wondered if the contact joint API was exposed in Gazebo.  Or if it would be possible to write a plugin to do get the forces.  Any help would be much appreciated as I'd really rather use Gazebo.

thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/286/contact-force-sensing/) by [mkillpack](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/100/mkillpack/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-11-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You should use a ContactSensor. Attach the sensor to a link, and it will report all the contacts on that link. This includes each contact's position, normal, depth, and forces.

Note: Some parts of the contact sensor will only work with the upcoming Gazebo 1.3 release.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1